# The regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

Good day, just want to apologize for my English - the fact that I am using Google translator.
Show you how in this regular expression in Python does not connect with the index named group 1 and group named 'ID111'?

This is the regular expression I am using:
`r'(^RU)?(?P<ID111>(?(1).+|[\d]{5}))'`

Here is the line where the search is performed:
`RU Д-SK.ПК05.В.02695.jpeg  (начинается с ТС)`

Here is a link to convenient service to check with the already exposed data a regular expression:
https://regex101.com/r/mDh0kZ/1

The fact is that if a line where we searched if returns true, then the group 'ID111' misses the entire line as intended and only what comes after a group of index 1.
I want to solve it with a regular expression only.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: So, what does not work and how should it work? Note that you may post the question in Russian [here](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: @WiktorStribizew It is necessary that at operation block `(1) + |? .` Shows the `RU D-SK.PK05.V.02695.jpeg (starts with TC)` rather than the `D-SK.PK05.V.02695.jpeg (begins with TS)`

Comment: I am not sure what you want to get in the end, but try `r'^RU.+|\d{5}'` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mxWqdG/3)). I think you want to use it with `re.search`, check if there is a match, and then grab the `match.group()` value.

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to what I need, but the result must be in the group `ID111`

Comment: Ok, use `r'(?P<ID111>^RU.+|\d{5})'` - is that OK?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much! I'm a little edit your expression, and found what I needed! If you want to issue it as your answer and I will make it as correct. <br/> Here is the expression that I came: `(?P<ID111>(?:(?=^RU).+(?=\..*)|\d{5}))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `(?P<ID111>^RU.+(?=\..*)|\d{5})` Your last option is even better;) Thanks again!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо Вам еще раз)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the conditional is not even necessary, all you need is use 2 alternatives: 1) match a string from the start if it starts with `RU` up to the last `.`, or 2) match a 5-digit chunk.

Thus, use

```
r'(?P<ID111>^RU.*(?=\.)|\d{5})'
```

See the [Python regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XscAC3/1)

**Details**:

- `^RU` - a `RU` at the start of the string
- `.*(?=\.)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars up to the last `.` (excluding it)
- `|` - or
- `\d{5}` - 5 digits (note that to match a 5-digit chunk not enclosed with other digits, use `(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)`).

Comment: Just FYI: `(?=\..*)` = `(?=\.)`